# What is the correct way to return from function?

Tags: go, recursion

I am confused how should I return a value from a function. I was trying the below example:

- Passing false to function a
- Value of c will be false in function a
- It will make a recursive call and this will change the value of c from false to true
- So function should return a string "true" and bool true but it is returning  a string "false" and bool false

  ```
  package main

  import (
      "fmt"
  )

  func a(c bool) (string, bool) {
      if c {
          return "true", true
      }
      a(true)
      return "false", false
  }

  func main() {
      s, ok := a(false)
     fmt.Println(s, ok)
  }
  ```

  https://play.golang.org/p/uSIN2k0G3QW

Comment: Why do you think you'll change the value of `c`? Nothing in your code changes that value.

Comment: Also your call within `a` to `a` is completely ignored.

Comment: @Flimzy function `a` should return true, true but it is returning false, false. that all  want to understand

Comment: Why do you think it should return true? It will only return true if `c` is true. If `c` is false, then it calls `a` again, ignoring the result, then returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive code will always return "false" false when `c` is false. Please see the correct code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func a(c bool) (string, bool) {
    if c {
        return "true", true
    }
    return a(true)
}

func main() {
    s, ok := a(false)
   fmt.Println(s, ok)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you think your code should do, but here's what it's actually doing:

1. You call `a` with the value `false`:

   It checks if `c` is true:

   ```
   if c {
   ```

   but it's not, so it contiues
2. It calls `a` again, this time with the value `true`, but completely ignoring the result:

   ```
   a(true)
   ```
3. Then it returns false:

   ```
   return "false", false
   ```

This means that step #2 is a complete no-op (and is probably removed entirely by the compiler).

Maybe you want to do something with the returned value of `a(true)`?

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a 2 level recursion. In first level you have c as false. Then you call a(true) and you are in second level which returns true. Now you are back in level 1 at line a(true) and the next line is to return false as string and bool. Hence you get false as final output.

I think you are trying to use the return value which is not the case right now.